# Can we show the login information made with the firebase authentication system as textview in the application?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have created a login-register system by using Firebase auth. Now I want to show the registration information (name, email, phone) in my app. I want to reflect the registration information to text view but I couldn't find the way to do that.

Registration class:
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
EditText mName, mEmail, mPassword, mPhone;
Button mRegisterButton;
TextView mLoginButton;
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    mName = findViewById(R.id.userName);
    mEmail = findViewById(R.id.userMail);
    mPassword = findViewById(R.id.userPassword);
    mPhone = findViewById(R.id.userPhone);
    mRegisterButton = findViewById(R.id.register_button);
    mLoginButton = findViewById(R.id.goToLogin);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

    mRegisterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String email = mEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = mPassword.getText().toString().trim();

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email))
            {
                mEmail.setError("Email is required");
                return;
            }
            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password))
            {
                mPassword.setError("Password is required");
                return;
            }

            if(password.length() < 0)
            {
                mPassword.setError("Password Must Be >= 6 Characters");
                return;
            }

            firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "User Created.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
                        Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                       

                    }else{
                        Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Error!" + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

    mLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class));
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: Is your onComplete triggered? If yes, is your Task successful?

Comment: What do you mean by triggered? My task is successful and registration- login processes works correctly.

Comment: If you add a log statement inside onComplete, do you have something printed out in the console?

Comment: Yes sir , " D/ContentValues: createUserWithEmail:success " message is printing .

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin code below;

```kotlin
fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    val curreentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser

    val name = currentUser?.displayName
    val email = currentUser?.email
    val phone = currentUser?.phoneNumber

    val textView = findViewById(R.id.your_text_view_id)
    textView.text = "$name, $email, $phone"
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer.I'm sorry for not specifying that the question is in the java language.Can you provide its Java version please?

Comment: Oh sorry, someone leaves in Java :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a TextView added in your layout, especially added to display the data, then right after the following line of code:

```
FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
```

Add these lines:

```
String name = user.getDisplayName();
String email = user.getEmail();
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
String text = name + "/" + email;
textView.setText(text);
```

Please also note that when you are using email and password authentication the phone number doesn't exist. So if you try to use it, you'll get null.